# NSDate and timezone differences

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

I have been browsing the apple docs and stackoverflow for a while now, but I wasn't be able to find a correct answer for my problem.
I'll try to explain. In my app a user is able to create measurements on a specific time. The date and time of the measurement is important.

In my NSDate+Helper category I created the following helper methods:

```
- (NSDate *)dateByMovingToBeginningOfDay
{
    unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents* parts = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:self];
    [parts setHour:0];
    [parts setMinute:0];
    [parts setSecond:0];
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:parts];
}

- (NSDate *)dateByMovingToEndOfDay {
    unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents* parts = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:self];
    [parts setHour:23];
    [parts setMinute:59];
    [parts setSecond:59];
    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:parts];
}
```

This methods helps me to get a range of measurements from a complete day:

```
NSDate *start = [[NSDate date] dateByMovingToBeginningOfDay];
NSDate *end   = [[NSDate date] dateByMovingToEndOfDay];

NSMutableSet *measurementsSet = [trainingsPlan measurementsWithType:@"used" fromDate:start andToDate:end];
```

There is where my problem comes in. Let's say I add a measurement on my simulator at `2012-03-14 0:42:59 (GMT+1)` -because that's the time displayed on my simulator- and save it in core data.

`[NSDate date]` at that moment is `2012-03-13 23:42:59` so `NSDate *start = [[NSDate date] dateByMovingToBeginningOfDay];` gives me the start date of the day before. This is a problem.

My question, what is the best approach that it will work for users in all different timezones?

Comment: [Apple Documentation: Date and Time Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html) has mention of NSTimeZone which may help.  I've never used it so I can't speak for its ability to solve your problem.

Comment: what's the problem exactly ? do you want to send the dated to the server not sending the timezone for each date ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the same data across multiple time zones then your only option is to use the same timezone in your app, no matter what time the iPad says.  Generally you use UTC for this purpose (and is the default time zone that times are created and saved in).

If you just want it to match the local timezone, then you need to change your routines like this:

```
- (NSDate *)dateByMovingToBeginningOfDay
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents* parts = [calendar components:flags fromDate:self];
    [parts setHour:0];
    [parts setMinute:0];
    [parts setSecond:0];

    return [calendar dateFromComponents:parts];
}
```

Update the second routine in the same way.

Comment: This method returns the date: 2012-03-14 23:00:00 +0000

Comment: It is 2300 UTC which is 0000 Local.  The debugger only shows UTC and anywhere else that you want to use it you need to specify the time zone.

Comment: Ok, I rethink a bit. Maybe it's better to just ignore the timezone differences and just take the dateByMovingToBeginningOfDay result as it is. I only need to find another way to get the selected month, because it isn't logical to ask it to the result of dateByMovingToBeginningOfDay. But that should not be that hard>. I just could add a couple of days to that date and extract the month.

Comment: If you calculate the time the same way when you take your measurements (or import the data if they are done outside of iOS), then they will all be corrected to UTC and your measurementsSet will correctly include  all of the measurements from 2300 UTC the night before to 2300 UTC of the day in question (which is 0000 Local - 0000 Local as expected).